# i get an error when trying to add an image to python tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

hi so have this image in the same directory as my .py file  . and i changed the image from "background.jpg" to "background.gif" because i heard it helps
when i hover my cursor over the file=background.gif it show me the image so it can read it
but when i try to run . it give me an error and says "couldn't recognize data in image file "background.gif""

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3fMM.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYZPX.png)

Comment: Please include the code in your post **not images.**

Comment: How do you change the image? Just rename it or use an image converter?

Comment: @acw1668 i just rename it

Comment: @acw1668 i used an online image converter and it worked . thanks alot

Comment: You can't just rename an image to change its format, just like you can't simply rename a file to switch the whole file from english to french.

Comment: Another option might be using `pillow` module, might help for future reference

Comment: Please don't use pictures of code and errors. They aren't searchable, copyable, and the visually impaired can't read them at all.

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry i just started using the website today . also what can i do if i solved my problem ?

Comment: @Mrmangaka ill add answer which you can hopefully mark as the ans and close the Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here really is(as acw1668 mentioned) because you didn't use an image converter to convert the image, instead just simply renamed the file to .gif, which is not the correct way of changing file formats and can damage the file at times. Using an [jpg to gif converter online](https://ezgif.com/jpg-to-gif) can clear this issue and give you a gif that works :D

Comment: Rename a file will not damage the file.  Currently most of the image libraries and applications don't use the file extensions to determine the image types.  They use some kind of signatures from the file headers to determine the image types.

Comment: @acw1668 mayb but i have tried renaming files which changes the format and corrupt the file and makes it unusable, Maybe your correct too :)